# how to extract useful data from a string obtained from a user?

Tags: python

> data = input('Enter data:\n')

> data = 'BEGIN 12.2_1014:18.6E,34.0S DIRDAM END' *basically these data can vary and therefore their spaces*

So the data provided contains the location which is in-between '0S' and 'END', (DIRDAM) which needs to reversed back to its proper order *MADRID*

The temperature in-between 'BEGIN' and '_' *underscore* (12.2)

The pressure which is between '_' *underscore* and ':' *colon*  (1014)

The location which starts after ":" *colon* and end before the the letter "S" *S indicates direction* (18.6E,34.0S) the directions could change from 'S' to 'N' or from 'E' to 'W' as well as the values direction could just be 4E,5N.

Now I could use slicing but because it is user inputted data the position may vary therefore the program will either cut out a piece of the information because the new information from the user is either longer or shorter and I have no idea how to extract those substrings properly. How to extract those individual information like the location...etc. Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend looking into regular expressions (`re` library). For the first example, you could do something like : `re.search("0S(.*)END", data).group(1).strip()` which will give you `DIRDAM`, which is easy to reverse

Comment: You need clear definitions of what constitutes permissible breaks and what they signify. For example would 'BEGIN 1014:12.2_18.6E,34.0S DIRDAM END' be a permissible way to express the same information? If the location is *NEW YORK* or *SAN MARINO*, would the space be included? Could the direction *S* be *N*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.split` and `str.strip`:

```py
data = input('Enter data: ')
data = data.split("BEGIN")[1] # get rid of the BEGIN at the beginning
temperature, data = data.split("_") # get the temperature
temperature = temperature.strip() # strip removes any trailing / beginning whitespaces
pressure, data = data.split(":") # get the pressure
pressure = pressure.strip()
lonlat, data = data.split("S", 1) # get longitude and latitude
lon, lat = (lonlat.strip() + "S").split(",") # add back the S we just splitted away above
city = data.split("END")[0].strip()[::-1] # get the city name and unreverse it
print(temperature, pressure, lon, lat, city)
```

Output:

```py
12.2 1014 18.6E 34.0S MADRID
```

Comment: This helped me so much I can't thank you enough I was struggling with the lon and lat part but you solved it, but say I change the 'S' to 'N' and 'E' to 'W' how would I modify the program then for the lon and lat?

Comment: @Asif No need to thank me - it's enough to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;) ! And for the changing, just replace the two `"S"` in the 7th and 8th line with `"N"`, and done !

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```py
import re

data = "BEGIN 12.2_1014:18.6E,34.0S DIRDAM END"

p = re.compile(
    r"BEGIN (?P<temp>\d+\.\d*)_(?P<pres>\d+):(?P<loc>\d+\.\d*[EW],\d+\.?\d*[NS]) (?P<city>\w+) END"
)
m = p.search(data)

res = m.groupdict()
res["temp"] = float(res["temp"])
res["pres"] = int(res["pres"])
res["city"] = res["city"][::-1]
print(res)
```

Comment: This was really helpful you solved my problem with the 'EW' and 'NS' but the thing is if I reduce the longitude and latitude to length of 2 only for eg. change '18.6E' to '6E' and change '34.0S' to '0S' how would i modify the problem

Comment: I you want to include both `18.6E` and `6E` then use `(?P<loc>\d+\.?\d*[EW],\d+\.?\d*[NS])`. Here the only mandatory part is the first `\d+` (+ meaning one or more digits) the rest is optional (`\.?` means 0 or 1 dot and `\d*` means 0 or more digits). This pattern would match numbers with or without decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the locationname ("DIRDAM" in this case) will never contain a digit or space (if I'm going to assume, I might as well assume in a way that makes my life easier!), and that no other types of data are introduced, the following will break it into sections for you to start splitting the strings down further...

```
data = 'BEGIN 12.2_1014:18.6E,34.0S DIRDAM END'

datalist = data.split()

for entry in datalist:
    if entry not in ("BEGIN","END"):
        if entry.isdigit():
            # This is now the string with temp/pressure/location
            # which, if fixed, can be split further. I'll leave
            # that to you, let's just print it for now
            print(entry)
        else:
            # This is now the string with locationname reversed
            # which can be corrected with a reverse slice
            print(entry[::-1])
```